# htaccess redirecting language and parameter not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

so I have a situation where I need to redirect a join page to the right language detected from user´s language browser, I can make that work easy, but the issue comes when I need to get that redirection along with a parameter from a referred customer, which should get forward and get recorded in cookies, but it´s not. I´ve tried this among others.. (I know it´s wrong):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^exec/customer/join /join?$1&language=spanish [R=301]
```

Where $1 is should be referral_Id=X (any number/s), is getting blocked and not recorded. How to get the redirect to the language and the same time the referral Id=4 gets recorded in cookies? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^exec/customer/join /join?language=spanish [R=301,L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Thank you! I don´t know why but it´s working without the L. Thanks for your help, have a nice day.